# Rails custom validation inside model which belongs_to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, custom-validators

i'm trying to learn ruby and trying to work with business rules and console through active record methods.
Here's the problem i'm facing right now, assume the following scenario:

I have 3 models:

```
Class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :animals

Class Animal < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :tipo

Class Tipo < ApplicationRecord
has_many :animals

respective migration:
User
t.string :name
t.string :doc
t.date   :birth_day

Animal
t.string  :name
t.decimal :mensal_cost

add_index :animals, :user_id
add_index :animals, :user_id

Tipo 
t.string :tipo_animal
```

I want to make a validation which get the the user_id and sum the mensal_cost
of all his animals,  so if this cost is higher than 1000 then he cant have more animals.

So i think i must to get the user id and sum his respectively animals.mensal_cost array

Ok now u're contextualized, ill set my code below.
PS. it's inside animal model:

```
#Want to get the total of a single user mensal cost
def total
  user_id.each do |mensal_cost|
  mensal_cost.inject(&:+)
end

#Now the custom validation itself

validate :check_mtotal

  def check_mtotal
    if user_id && total > 1000
    errors.add(:user_id, message: 'cant add more animals')
  end
end
```

Well, first problem is that my total isn't returning anything, so i really don't know how make it proceed to get the ammount of mensal_cost of a single user.

second... i need the first problem solve to test the second :(.

anyone can help with this?

Thank you very much for your attention

Comment: Your question is quite wide, maybe if you narrow down your problem you can either find a question that already exists or ask one that will be precise enough to be useful for the community?

Comment: trust me i already search for it. And yest war intentional, since i'm learnin, i think there's another, and i think the question is clear and not fragmented, which becomes easy to undertand even for those who's begining like me.

Comment: So instead of doing what I suggested, you say that what I just said doesn't apply. Okay, good talk!

Comment: Well, you didn`t help at all. i wouldn`t post a question here of this size and detailed like that if i`ve found anything that i could understand to paply propperly.
But instead of complain about the size of the question u could read that and try to help, propperly.

Comment: Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to add animals to user?

Comment: Pavittar Gill, no i didn't even know this method. How should i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i figured out the solution and it's below:

```
User model
#Returns the total mensal cost
def max_mensal
  animals.sum(:mensal_cost)
end

Animal model
#Validates the mensal ammount

validate :check_form_mammount

def check_for_mammount
  if user_id && user.max_mensal > (value here)
  errors.add(:mensal_cost, message: 'msg here')
end
```